# convert dataframe to new list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data.table

I have a data.frame NOAA_OLR_TEST

```
NOAA_OLR_TEST <- structure(list(DATE_START = structure(c(1170720000, 1170806400,
1170892800, 1170979200, 1171065600, 1171152000, 1171238400, 1171324800,
1171411200, 1171497600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
DATE_END = structure(c(1171065600,1171152000, 1171238400, 1171324800, 
1171411200, 1171497600, 1171584000,1171670400, 1171756800, 1171843200), 
class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), LONGITUDE = c(-89.5, -89.5, -89.5, -89.5, 
-89.5, -88.5, -88.5,-88.5, -88.5, -88.5), LATITUDE = c(-179.5, -179.5, -179.5, 
-179.5,-179.5, -179.5, -179.5, -179.5, -179.5, -179.5), OLR_DATA_1 = c(150,146, 
146, 142, NA, 150, 158, 155, 143, 142), OLR_DATA_2 = c(146,146, 142, 141, 150, 
NA, 155, 143, 142, 138), OLR_DATA_3 = c(146,NA, 141, 150, 158, 155, 143, 142, 
138, 135), OLR_DATA_4 = c(142,141, 150, 158, 155, 143, 142, 138, 135, NA), 
OLR_DATA_5 = c(141,150, NA, 155, 143, 142, 138, 135, 140, 139)), 
.Names = c("DATE_START","DATE_END", "LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE", "OLR_DATA_1", 
"OLR_DATA_2","OLR_DATA_3", "OLR_DATA_4", "OLR_DATA_5"), row.names = c(NA,10L), 
class = "data.frame")
```

my expect is to convert No.5 to No.9 columns of the dataframes NOAA_OLR_TEST[5:9] to list

Comment: Note that a data frame is already a `list()`, which is why its columns can be accessed with the `$` form of the extract operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(NOAA_OLR_TEST)
NOAA_OLR_TEST[,xy.list:=list(OLR_DATA_1,OLR_DATA_2,OLR_DATA_3,OLR_DATA_4,OLR_DATA_5)]
NOAA_OLR_TEST[,(5:9):= NULL]

is.list(NOAA_OLR_TEST$xy.list)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: thanks, how to remove old data NOAA_OLR_TEST[5:9] in new data.table NOAA_OLR_TEST

Comment: @Pan I added this line: `NOAA_OLR_TEST[,(5:9):= NULL]` to remove the original columns.

Comment: thanks a lot, it is good answer, but it may not I want, can you have a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47495118/combine-five-columns-of-a-dataframe-to-two-new-lists

Comment: You can't accept, unaccept, accept and unaccept again because you want help on another question. If this answer solves the problem in this specific question, accept once and for all­.

Comment: Hi I am sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

Just use `c(...)`:

```
lst <- c(NOAA_OLR_TEST)[5:9];
#lst;
#List of 5
# $ OLR_DATA_1: num [1:10] 150 146 146 142 NA 150 158 155 143 142
# $ OLR_DATA_2: num [1:10] 146 146 142 141 150 NA 155 143 142 138
# $ OLR_DATA_3: num [1:10] 146 NA 141 150 158 155 143 142 138 135
# $ OLR_DATA_4: num [1:10] 142 141 150 158 155 143 142 138 135 NA
# $ OLR_DATA_5: num [1:10] 141 150 NA 155 143 142 138 135 140 139
```

Or with `lapply`:

```
lst <- lapply(5:9, function(i) NOAA_OLR_TEST[, i])
```

Comment: How can I combine NOAA_OLR_TEST[1:4] and lst?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do you want to add the other 4 columns as a `dataframe`? In that case you can do `lst <- c(NOAA_OLR_TEST)[5:9]; lst[[length(lst) + 1]] <- NOAA_OLR_TEST[, 1:4];`.

Comment: Wait. In your original post you state that you "want to convert No.5 to No.9 **columns**".  Now you're talking about turning rows into list elements? And then combine something with something else? What do you mean by combine? My previous comment already shows how you add a `dataframe` as a list element. Please be precise in your statements. I've got no idea what you mean.

Comment: thanks a lot, it is good answer, but it may not I want, can you have a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47495118/combine-five-columns-of-a-dataframe-to-two-new-lists

Answer (score 0):

The question and subsequent comments by the OP are confusing what result the OP is expecting. So, I offer different variants:

#### Return a data.table with just columns 5:9

```
library(data.table)
NOAA_OLR_TEST_new <- setDT(NOAA_OLR_TEST)[, .SD, .SDcols = 5:9]
str(NOAA_OLR_TEST_new)
```

> ```
> Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    10 obs. of  5 variables:
>  $ OLR_DATA_1: num  150 146 146 142 NA 150 158 155 143 142
>  $ OLR_DATA_2: num  146 146 142 141 150 NA 155 143 142 138
>  $ OLR_DATA_3: num  146 NA 141 150 158 155 143 142 138 135
>  $ OLR_DATA_4: num  142 141 150 158 155 143 142 138 135 NA
>  $ OLR_DATA_5: num  141 150 NA 155 143 142 138 135 140 139
>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
> ```

Note that data.frames and data.tables are special forms of a list.

#### Return columns 5:9 as list

```
NOAA_OLR_TEST_new <- as.list(setDT(NOAA_OLR_TEST)[, .SD, .SDcols = 5:9])
str(NOAA_OLR_TEST_new)
```

> ```
> List of 5
>  $ OLR_DATA_1: num [1:10] 150 146 146 142 NA 150 158 155 143 142
>  $ OLR_DATA_2: num [1:10] 146 146 142 141 150 NA 155 143 142 138
>  $ OLR_DATA_3: num [1:10] 146 NA 141 150 158 155 143 142 138 135
>  $ OLR_DATA_4: num [1:10] 142 141 150 158 155 143 142 138 135 NA
>  $ OLR_DATA_5: num [1:10] 141 150 NA 155 143 142 138 135 140 139
> ```

#### Convert columns 5:9 as a list column of a data.table

```
NOAA_OLR_TEST_new <- setDT(NOAA_OLR_TEST)[, .(as.list(.SD)), .SDcols = 5:9]
str(NOAA_OLR_TEST_new)
```

> ```
> Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    5 obs. of  1 variable:
>  $ V1:List of 5
>   ..$ : num  150 146 146 142 NA 150 158 155 143 142
>   ..$ : num  146 146 142 141 150 NA 155 143 142 138
>   ..$ : num  146 NA 141 150 158 155 143 142 138 135
>   ..$ : num  142 141 150 158 155 143 142 138 135 NA
>   ..$ : num  141 150 NA 155 143 142 138 135 140 139
>   ..- attr(*, ".data.table.locked")= logi TRUE
>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
> ```

Comment: thanks, it is good answer, but it may not I want, can you have a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47495118/combine-five-columns-of-a-dataframe-to-two-new-lists