# Combine five columns of a dataframe to two new lists

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data.table

I have a data.frame `NOAA_OLR_TEST`:

```
NOAA_OLR_TEST <- structure(list(DATE_START = structure(c(1170720000, 1170806400,
1170892800, 1170979200, 1171065600, 1171152000, 1171238400, 1171324800,
1171411200, 1171497600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
DATE_END = structure(c(1171065600,1171152000, 1171238400, 1171324800, 
1171411200, 1171497600, 1171584000,1171670400, 1171756800, 1171843200), 
class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), LONGITUDE = c(-89.5, -89.5, -89.5, -89.5, 
-89.5, -88.5, -88.5,-88.5, -88.5, -88.5), LATITUDE = c(-179.5, -179.5, -179.5, 
-179.5,-179.5, -179.5, -179.5, -179.5, -179.5, -179.5), OLR_DATA_1 = c(150,146, 
146, 142, NA, 150, 158, 155, 143, 142), OLR_DATA_2 = c(146,146, 142, 141, 150, 
NA, 155, 143, 142, 138), OLR_DATA_3 = c(146,NA, 141, 150, 158, 155, 143, 142, 
138, 135), OLR_DATA_4 = c(142,141, 150, 158, 155, 143, 142, 138, 135, NA), 
OLR_DATA_5 = c(141,150, NA, 155, 143, 142, 138, 135, 140, 139)), 
.Names = c("DATE_START","DATE_END", "LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE", "OLR_DATA_1", 
"OLR_DATA_2","OLR_DATA_3", "OLR_DATA_4", "OLR_DATA_5"), row.names = c(NA,10L), 
class = "data.frame")
```

Here is my data:

`head(NOAA_OLR_TEST)`

```
 DATE_START   DATE_END LONGITUDE LATITUDE OLR_DATA_1 OLR_DATA_2 OLR_DATA_3 OLR_DATA_4 OLR_DATA_5
1 2007-02-06 2007-02-10     -89.5   -179.5        150        146        146        142        141
2 2007-02-07 2007-02-11     -89.5   -179.5        146        146         NA        141        150
3 2007-02-08 2007-02-12     -89.5   -179.5        146        142        141        150         NA
4 2007-02-09 2007-02-13     -89.5   -179.5        142        141        150        158        155
5 2007-02-10 2007-02-14     -89.5   -179.5         NA        150        158        155        143
6 2007-02-11 2007-02-15     -88.5   -179.5        150         NA        155        143        142
```

my expect is to convert No.5 to No.9 columns of the dataframes `NOAA_OLR_TEST[5:9]` to two lists named `data_list_1` and `data_list_2`:

```
 DATE_START   DATE_END LONGITUDE LATITUDE        DATA_LIST_1     DATA_LIST_2  
1 2007-02-06 2007-02-10     -89.5   -179.5        (150 ,146)      (146,142,141)
2 2007-02-07 2007-02-11     -89.5   -179.5        (146 ,146)      ( NA,141,150)
3 2007-02-08 2007-02-12     -89.5   -179.5        (146 ,142)      (141,150, NA)
4 2007-02-09 2007-02-13     -89.5   -179.5        (142 ,141)      (150,158,155)
5 2007-02-10 2007-02-14     -89.5   -179.5        ( NA ,150)      (158,155,143)
6 2007-02-11 2007-02-15     -88.5   -179.5        (150 , NA)      (155,143,142)
```

I use mapply，Map，cbind, all of them have some erros.

Comment: How is this question significantly different from the one [you asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47474279/covert-dataframe-to-new-list)? You've received **a lot** of answers to the previous one, none of which you actually seem to have considered. You're not going to be very popular around here, if you just keep re-posting the same/similar questions whilst ignoring responses that others have given you.

Comment: Thanks for comments, but it is a different one, it have 2 lists and each one have different number of columns

Comment: Not different at all. The **exact same** concepts and solutions that were presented to you in response to your previous question apply here as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** If you want to the data to behave as a list, your won't be able to see it in a table as a comma separated string. However, the data will still be available as a normal list.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(NOAA_OLR_TEST)
NOAA_OLR_TEST[, DATA_LIST_1 := lapply(transpose(.SD), as.list), 
              .SDcols = c("OLR_DATA_1","OLR_DATA_2")]
NOAA_OLR_TEST[, DATA_LIST_2 := lapply(transpose(.SD), as.list), 
              .SDcols = c("OLR_DATA_3","OLR_DATA_4","OLR_DATA_5")]
NOAA_OLR_TEST[,(5:9):= NULL]
             DATE_START            DATE_END LONGITUDE LATITUDE DATA_LIST_1 DATA_LIST_2
 1: 2007-02-05 19:00:00 2007-02-09 19:00:00     -89.5   -179.5      <list>      <list>
 2: 2007-02-06 19:00:00 2007-02-10 19:00:00     -89.5   -179.5      <list>      <list>
 3: 2007-02-07 19:00:00 2007-02-11 19:00:00     -89.5   -179.5      <list>      <list>
 4: 2007-02-08 19:00:00 2007-02-12 19:00:00     -89.5   -179.5      <list>      <list>
 5: 2007-02-09 19:00:00 2007-02-13 19:00:00     -89.5   -179.5      <list>      <list>
 6: 2007-02-10 19:00:00 2007-02-14 19:00:00     -88.5   -179.5      <list>      <list>
 7: 2007-02-11 19:00:00 2007-02-15 19:00:00     -88.5   -179.5      <list>      <list>
 8: 2007-02-12 19:00:00 2007-02-16 19:00:00     -88.5   -179.5      <list>      <list>
 9: 2007-02-13 19:00:00 2007-02-17 19:00:00     -88.5   -179.5      <list>      <list>
10: 2007-02-14 19:00:00 2007-02-18 19:00:00     -88.5   -179.5      <list>      <list>
```

To show that the lists are indeed numeric:

```
first_row <- NOAA_OLR_TEST[DATE_START==as.POSIXct("2007-02-05 19:00:00")]
str(first_row$DATA_LIST_1[[1]])
List of 2
 $ OLR_DATA_1: num 150
 $ OLR_DATA_2: num 146
```

Comment: class(NOAA_OLR_TEST$DATA_LIST_1) is [1] "character", can let it be number

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `apply` for that as follows:

```
NOAA_OLR_TEST_2 <- NOAA_OLR_TEST[, 1:4]
NOAA_OLR_TEST_2$list1 <- apply(NOAA_OLR_TEST[, 5:6], 1, list)
NOAA_OLR_TEST_2$list2 <- apply(NOAA_OLR_TEST[, 7:9], 1, list)
NOAA_OLR_TEST_2
```

The result:

```
> NOAA_OLR_TEST_2
            DATE_START            DATE_END LONGITUDE LATITUDE    list1         list2
1  2007-02-06 01:00:00 2007-02-10 01:00:00     -89.5   -179.5 150, 146 146, 142, 141
2  2007-02-07 01:00:00 2007-02-11 01:00:00     -89.5   -179.5 146, 146  NA, 141, 150
3  2007-02-08 01:00:00 2007-02-12 01:00:00     -89.5   -179.5 146, 142  141, 150, NA
4  2007-02-09 01:00:00 2007-02-13 01:00:00     -89.5   -179.5 142, 141 150, 158, 155
5  2007-02-10 01:00:00 2007-02-14 01:00:00     -89.5   -179.5  NA, 150 158, 155, 143
6  2007-02-11 01:00:00 2007-02-15 01:00:00     -88.5   -179.5  150, NA 155, 143, 142
7  2007-02-12 01:00:00 2007-02-16 01:00:00     -88.5   -179.5 158, 155 143, 142, 138
8  2007-02-13 01:00:00 2007-02-17 01:00:00     -88.5   -179.5 155, 143 142, 138, 135
9  2007-02-14 01:00:00 2007-02-18 01:00:00     -88.5   -179.5 143, 142 138, 135, 140
10 2007-02-15 01:00:00 2007-02-19 01:00:00     -88.5   -179.5 142, 138  135, NA, 139
```

If want to exclude `NA`-values, you can adapt the code to:

```
NOAA_OLR_TEST_2 <- NOAA_OLR_TEST[, 1:4]
NOAA_OLR_TEST_2$list1 <- apply(NOAA_OLR_TEST[, 5:6], 1, function(x) list(na.omit(x)))
NOAA_OLR_TEST_2$list2 <- apply(NOAA_OLR_TEST[, 7:9], 1, function(x) list(na.omit(x)))
```

Comment: thanks, how to remove NA in this case, I use lapply(list, function(x) x[!is.na(x)]), but id does not work

Comment: @Pan You can use `na.omit`, see my updated answer.

Comment: thanks, how can I remove NOAA_OLR_TEST_2$list2 . use NOAA_OLR_TEST_2$list2 <- null ?

Comment: @Pan yes, but use capital letters: `NOAA_OLR_TEST_2$list2 <- NULL`

Comment: when I use tsclust (NOAA_OLR_TEST_2$list2,...) function, it have errors: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : The series must be numeric

Answer (score 0):

Here is my `mutate(pmap())` approach:

```
# "name =" isn't necessary.
d1 <- NOAA_OLR_TEST %>% 
  # as.tibble() %>% 
  mutate(data_list_1 = pmap(., ~ c(OLR_DATA_1 = ..5, OLR_DATA_2 = ..6)), 
         data_list_2 = pmap(., ~ c(OLR_DATA_3 = ..7, OLR_DATA_4 = ..8, OLR_DATA_5 = ..9))) %>% 
  select(-(5:9))

d2 <- NOAA_OLR_TEST %>% 
  # as.tibble() %>% 
  mutate(data_list_1 = pmap(., ~ list(OLR_DATA_1 = ..5, OLR_DATA_2 = ..6)), 
         data_list_2 = pmap(., ~ list(OLR_DATA_3 = ..7, OLR_DATA_4 = ..8, OLR_DATA_5 = ..9))) %>% 
  select(-(5:9))

d1
d1 %>% as.tibble()
d2 %>% as.tibble()
```